# .js and .css files suddenly giving 404, making the entire website become without any formatting or functionality!

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, javascript, css, cache

This morning I got a call from our client about how their website is no longer loading correctly, showing all text, no formatting, etc.. Even the admin page login wasn't working correctly.

I opened the website and I got this error:
[image]

All coming from `.js` and `.css` files. Upon clearing the `var/cache` folder from the command line, it worked again all on its own.

However, I still can't figure out what caused the error to prevent from happening again. Apache and Magento error logs show nothing aside from the 404 for the files.

What could possibly have caused this error? And how to prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got your point

1) Login admin panel

2) go to `Sytem->Configuration->General->Web-> Unsecure`

3) change `Base Skin URL` to `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`

4) `Sytem->Configuration->General->Web-> Secure`

5) for this also `Base Skin URL` to `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`

6) go to `system->Cache Management` and Refresh the cache.

Comment: I also faced this situation before 6 months. i did like as you suggested here. this is good and clear solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Murtuza. The error never happened again, so I never got around to test such a solution, but I'll accept your answer for future searches that might help someone. :)