# Site Has Give Error NetworkError: 404 Not Found

Tags: magento-1.9, error, frontend-error

Site gives error like **NetworkError: 404 Not Found**

[image]

Comment: Site was Password Protected

Comment: Follow this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109359/js-and-css-files-suddenly-giving-404-making-the-entire-website-become-without

Comment: also check: https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/

Comment: In Chrome It's Work Correctly, But if i open in mozilla, then it's have more time to load site, and give this Error....

Answer (score 0):

- Login admin panel and go to Sytem->Configuration->General->Web.
- Change below values for unsecure section:

> Base Skin URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
>
> Base Js URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
>
> Base Media URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}media/

- Similarly, change below values for secure section:

> Base Skin URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
>
> Base Js URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
>
> Base Media URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}media/

- Go to **System -> Cache Management** and Refresh the cache.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: In Chrome It's Work Correctly, But if i open in mozilla, then it's have more time to load site, and give this Error....

Comment: If it does work in some browser, and it doesn't in others it's probably browser cache. Please make sure you reload the JS en CSS properly.